# What is the purpose of aws-cdk-lib vs @aws-cdk/core, @aws-cdk/aws-iam, ...?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I see various examples of using the AWS CDK where some use aws-cdk-lib and others use @aws-cdk/core. What is the difference between these and when should one or the other be used?

Comment: Short answer, @aws-cdk/(core,cloudfront,gateway) it's a better library distribution.
You can find full information here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html

Comment: is outrageously confusing. Examples online have two variants, the same names but incompatible types. Both libraries seem to be needed for different scenarios (i.e., the Amplify construct only works with the @aws-cdk). Overall very confusing and frustrating for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

aws-cdk-lib is CDK v2 modules and @aws-cdk/core is v1, you should use V2 instead